# Sed syntax - break down

Tags: bash, sed

I'm wondering if someone can help me to understand the following command. The purpose of this command is to purge the old kernels however I would like to understand the syntax:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

This is what I have so far:

**dpkg -l 'linux-*'** - list packages contain *"linux-*"* pattern

**sed '/^ii/!d;/'...** - find the lines starting with **ii** but don't contain **d;**

**"$(uname -r | sed "s/(.*)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")"'/d** - command substitution to list the current kernel and extract only the number from the version, **sed "s/(.*)...** - search for any number of characters, **...([^0-9]...** - starting with numbers 0-9, I don't understand this bit: **...+)/\1/...**

I'm completely lost with this one:

**s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'** - is it looking for empty characters starting the string?

Regards

Comment: Close; you're not quite breaking it down right though. Almost the whole command, up to the xargs, is just one long argument to the first sed. Do you see? When you put strings right next to each other, like 'arg'"$(command)" above, they are treated by the shell as one long uninterupted string. Secondly, read sed's man page. It's actually very flexible, and has a whole load of cryptic commands. /^ii/!d; is a command, ended by the ; with d specifying the instruction to sed, and the bit before describes the lines it applies to. Keep analysing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we have one long `sed` command here to analyse:

```
'/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
```

It's fed a list of packages matching 'linux-*' in `dpkg` syntax, which is a bit cryptic to start with, but the start of the lines indicates information about the package state.

The `sed` command itself is quite long (though I'm guilty of worse!), but fairly straightforward, with no looping or complications. `sed`, as the Fine Manual would tell you, accepts programs as a list of commands separated by semi-colons. So, the given `sed` program has four commands.

Firstly, '/^ii/!d'. We delete lines which don't start with 'ii'. Simple enough. We're looking for installed packages to remove.

Secondly, '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/(.*)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")"'/d'. This is a command-line within a command-line (using `bash`'s $() syntax), so we'll work from the inside out. The aim is clearly to filter out from the list of packages our currently running kernel so we don't remove it. The output from `uname -r` doesn't quite match the debian package names, so it's filtered from something like "3.0.0-generic" to just "3.0.0". The inner `sed` command, "s/(.*)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")", is just a simple regular expression search-and-replace that cuts off the end of the input after any hyphen. After $() substitution, the outer `sed` command looks like this '/3.0.0/d' (depending on kernel you're running). It just deletes lines that contain your current kernel version number.

Thirdly and fourthly, 's/^[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*/\1/' and '/[0-9]/!d' are the final filters. The first one again is a basic search-and-replace (it would be much clearer done in `awk`) that extracts the third field of the line, which will be the package name, and after that we delete lines which don't contain a digit (or else we'd remove the meta-packages that pull in the kernel upgrades).

Finally, `xargs` grabs its input line-by-line and runs the command you pass it on each line, with the line appended to its arguments. So, we remove each package we've found.

Comment: Edit: actually, I've just tried running the command, and I take back what I said about the third command. There's actually a bug in the original command you posted, and it only works by accident. It would have been more clear in awk! The original author clearly meant to write `s/^[^ ]* *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/`. Oh well.